# Drupal #states how to make it work

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, states

I'm trying to make #states work on drupal, I have a select field like this :

```
 $form['options'][$default_set_id]['none']['order_fields'][$field_name] = array(
    '#type' => $widget_types[$order_field['widget']['type']],
    '#suffix' => '<div class="field-description">' . $order_field['description'] . '</div>',
    '#title' => $order_field['label'],
    '#default_value' => '',
    '#options' => field_info_field($field_name)['settings']['allowed_values']
  );
```

and my field that need the #states :

```
$form['options'][$default_set_id]['none']['order_fields'][$field_name] = array(
    '#type' => $widget_types[$order_field['widget']['type']],
    '#suffix' => '<div class="field-description">' . $order_field['description'] . '</div>',
    '#title' => $order_field['label'],
    '#default_value' => isset($current_options['order_fields'][$field_name]) ? $current_options['order_fields'][$field_name] : '',
     '#states' => array(
      'visible' => array(
        ':select[name="field_transport_rdv"]' => array('value' => 'autre'),
      )
    )

  );
```

I'm doing all like in the documentation and examples I found in internet, but it seems not work, anyone have an idea ?

Comment: Use :input instead :select https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/

Comment: Why did you declare this field twice? $form['options'][$default_set_id]['none']['order_fields'][$field_name]. And I'm agree with the @lamp5 comments.

Comment: The field is declared once, the variable field_name change. I found my error, it works with :select too, the error was the name, jquery needs the full name so I put [name="options[defaut][none][order_fields][field_transport_rdv]"]